# Django ValueError when posting data to DB from HTML form - how to assign Foreign Key from option list?

Tags: django

When posting data to database from HTML page I am getting

ValueError at /add_emp/

Cannot assign "'Female'": "PersonInfo.gender" must be a "Gender" instance

I was trying to get the gender list under the html option list so that users can select one during post. My code looks as follows. I am new to django and self teaching from the internet.

```
**Models.py**

class Gender(models.Model):
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.gender


class PersonInfo(models.Model):
    pid = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=False)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=False)
    birth_date = models.DateField(blank=False)
    gender = models.ForeignKey(Gender, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return(f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}")


**Views.py**


def add_emp(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        all_record = PersonInfo.objects.all()
        # Show Form
        if request.method == "POST":

            pid = request.POST['pid']
            first_name = request.POST['first_name']
            middle_name = request.POST['middle_name']
            last_name = request.POST['last_name']
            birth_date = request.POST['birth_date']
            gender = request.POST['gender']


            new_employee = PersonInfo(pid=pid, first_name=first_name, middle_name=middle_name, last_name=last_name, birth_date=birth_date, gender=gender)
            new_employee.save()
            messages.success(request, "Employee Added")
            return render(request, 'add_emp.html', {'all_record': all_record})
        else:
            return render(request, 'add_emp.html', {'all_record': all_record})
    else:
        messages.success(request, "Access denied")
        return redirect('lobby')


**add_emp.html**

      <select name="gender" class="form-select">
        <option selected>Select Gender</option>
          {% for gender in all_record %}
            <option> {{ gender.gender }} </option>
          {% endfor %}
      </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the `Gender` object **itself** and pass it to `PersonInfo`

```py
def add_emp(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        all_record = PersonInfo.objects.all()
        # Show Form
        if request.method == "POST":

            pid = request.POST['pid']
            first_name = request.POST['first_name']
            middle_name = request.POST['middle_name']
            last_name = request.POST['last_name']
            birth_date = request.POST['birth_date']

            # .filter().first() will return the matching object or `None`
            gender_obj = Gender.objects.filter(gender=request.POST['gender']).first()

            new_employee = PersonInfo(
                pid=pid,
                first_name=first_name,
                middle_name=middle_name,
                last_name=last_name,
                birth_date=birth_date,
                gender=gender_obj
            )
            new_employee.save()
            messages.success(request, "Employee Added")
            return render(request, 'add_emp.html', {'all_record': all_record})
        else:
            return render(request, 'add_emp.html', {'all_record': all_record})
    else:
        messages.success(request, "Access denied")
        return redirect('lobby')
```

### Edit

Just clarifying my use of `.filter().first()`..

You could have also put `Gender.objects.get(gender=request.POST['gender'])` **but** it it didn't find any items with that column it would **crash** (like a real crash, an uncontrolled error)
Generally, I think it's a good route to always do `.filter().first()` and even with the `request.POST` I always use `request.post.get('gender')`.. which will return the value passed or `None` if nothing was passed, similar to `.filter().first()`

Comment: Amazing, it worked. I can't thank you enough. Any tip on what i should study to learn it better or any YouTube video on this topic?

Comment: Not really!- Just keep playing around and learning tidbits, they add up. based on the question tho, you should probably look into `Django Forms`